# Minimum of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, analysis, problem-solving

I would like to solve the following problem:

Peter has 2 accounts in a bank, each with an integral number of
dollars $A$ and $B$. He is only allowed to transfer money from one account to
another so that the amount of money in the latter is doubled. What is the minimum value of $\mid A_i-B_i \mid$ that Peter can get ?

I don't really know how to solve this problem. If we denote $f(A,B) = \min \mid A_i - B_i \mid$, then for example we have:

$$f(10, 17) = 1$$
$$f(4, 100) = 8$$
$$f(3, 7) = 2$$

But I am not able to find any logic. If $ A = 2B$ then $f(A,B) = B$. Otherwise I tried writing: $B = qA + r$, but wasn't able to find a way through. Any ideas ?

Comment: Hmmm - it might be useful to first consider the case that both A and B are powers of 2. Once you've figured out the pattern for powers of 2, then see if you can abstract to cases where they aren't powers of 2.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but rather an explanation of a convenient way to view the problem that might lead to a solution.

We can simplify the problem as follows:

- If $A$ and $B$ have a common factor, $d$, then the answer is $d$ times the answer to the same question for $A/d$ and $B/d$. Therefore, we can assume $A$ and $B$ are coprime.
- If $A$ and $B$ are both odd, then after one step they will be both even, which means we can divide by $2$. Therefore, we can assume that $A$ and $B$ are not both odd.

The only remaining cases are when one of $A$ and $B$ is odd, and the other is even. This property will persist as we make moves.

If we are currently in the state $(A,B)$, where $A<B$, then the next move is to
$$
(A,B)\longrightarrow (2A,B-A)=(2A,2B-(A+B))
$$
Let us look at this transformation modulo $(A+B)$. For example, in the case where $(A,B)=(10,17)$, we are considering the problem modulo $27$. Since $A+B\equiv 0\pmod{A+B}$, the above can be written as
$$
(A,B)\longrightarrow (2A,2B)\pmod{A+B}
$$
In other words, we are simply doubling both coordinates modulo $(A+B)$. This makes the problem very simple to analyze. First of all, modulo $A+B$, the state is equal to $(A,B)\equiv (A,-A)\pmod{A+B}$, so the entire situation is summarized by the first coordinate alone. After $k$ moves, the state of the problem will be
$$
(2^k A,-2^kA)
$$
The difference between these two is smallest when $2^kA\equiv (A+B\pm 1)/2$. The question is, how close does $2^kA\pmod {A+B}$ come to $(A+B+1)/2$?

As long as $2$ is a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n), then then $2^k$ will assume every value modulo $(A+B)$, so you can certainly bring $A$ and $B$ to their closest possible absolute difference of one. But there are not a lot of general things that can be said about the powers of $2$ modulo a general odd number, so I cannot think about how to proceed in general.